# Passing path string as arguments in Matlab bash

Tags: bash, matlab, matlab-deployment

I want to pass string path to matlab function that I defined and have encountered problem. Here is the summary of what I tried:

I am trying to pass a string variable (in this case a path) declared in bash script to pass that variable to my own function. e.g.

```
var=/usr/local/
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "my_function($var)"
```

I got the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

To solve this, I tried:

```
var=/usr/local/
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "my_function\($var\)"
```

which is not something I find in standard references I find online. Regardless, the matlab runs, but I get the error:

```
Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
```

To see if the variable is correctly converted, I tried echo:

```
var=/usr/local/
echo matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "my_function\($var\)"
```

and realized that the output is:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "my_function(/usr/local/)"
```

Since the variable is not string, the error made sense and I tried:

```
var=/usr/local/
var=$(printf "'%s'" $var)
echo matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "my_function\($var\)"
```

which shows:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "my_function('/usr/local/')"
```

So, I run the above code, but I still encounter the error:

```
Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
```

To check if the function exists in path, I tried both pwd and exist() for file. e.g.

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nojvm -r "exist('my_function.m')"
```

The strange thing in this case is that I did not need `\(\)` and that returned 2, meaning file exists in current path.

I am running out of ideas to try. So let me know how to solve this.

Comment: this is a a bash question not a matlab question

Answer (score 1):

So I created a function (myfunc) that takes path as an argument and prints list of files in that folder (ls).

```
$v='~/Documents'
$v2="myfunc('$v')"
$echo $v2
myfunc('~/Documents')
$matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r $v2
```

It works. Could you please try this and share your output?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem; I do not get the first bash error that you describe. Definitely one problem is missing ' ' around $var.

This works for me (granted that my_function is within the matlab path)

```
var=/usr/local/
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "my_function('$var')"
```

Alternatively try this without -r and like this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=/usr/local/
path_to_my_function=/some/path  

matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm << EOF
    addpath('${path_to_my_function}')
    my_function('${var}')
EOF
```